# recursive tree in jquery

Tags: jquery, hibernate, spring, tree

Can any one suggest jqueryTree I am using spring, hibernate, jsp.

Comment: Changed tags: hibernate is irrelevant to this question. so is spring, unless you mean the spring-mvc web framework

Comment: Rather changing tags give me answer dear..

Comment: He does say that he is using Spring, Hibernate and JSP. So technically, the tags were relevant...

Comment: @Neurofluxiation If he uses Windows on a Dell laptop to write the code, are 'Windows' and 'Dell' also appropriate tags?

Answer (score 2):

[the best one](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/)